# How to monitor the data I am sending and getting from the browser with each request to the server?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using chrome as a browser, and I am not sure my client is sending some data to the server or not. How to check or ensure the data(name value pair) client is sending and also getting with each request. Can you suggest any tool to do that or I can do it in Chorme dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the Network tab on the Dev tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the devtool). if you don't see any records added to the list - make sure that you are recording network log (clicking the left dot so it is red):
[image]

Then when you find the record that you were looking for - click on the row, and you'll be able to see the data in the relevant tab

[image]

under "Headers" you'll find the request parameters (`GET` params under `Query String Parameters` and `POST` params under `Form Data`)

and ynder "Response" you'll find the content of the response from the server

If you want tool that works independently from the browser. You should look for "sniffer"s - the one I recommend called Fiddler. It's free

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the dev tools and check the `Network` tab.
In there you can filter for `XHR` and see the requests and responses you are sending/receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Rest Client. I suggest you Postman. You can check the headers to see the data that the server is receiving.